# Data Stream via WebSocket from Spotify URL

Tags: c++, websocket, spotify

I have a link for a song preview from Spotify (example: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/...") and when I open this link music starts playing. I was wondering if it is possible to access this data from the song as a stream, using sockets. Basically, as the song plays in the web browser I store the song data in a buffer for example. Is is possible to achieve this?

I tried something in C++ to connect to the server using uWebSockets:

```
// Create a uWS WebSocket instance
uWS::Hub h;

// Connect to the WebSocket server
h.connect("https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/...", nullptr);

// Add an event handler for the 'open' event
auto onData = [&](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::CLIENT> *ws, uWS::HttpRequest req) {
    std::cout << "WebSocket connection opened" << std::endl;
    ws->send("Test message");
};

// Add an event handler for the 'message' event
auto onMessage =[&](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::CLIENT> *ws, char *message, size_t length, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
    std::cout << "WebSocket message received: " << std::string(message, length) << std::endl;
};

// Add an event handler for the 'close' event
auto onDisconnection = [&](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::CLIENT> *ws, int code, char *message, size_t length) {
    std::cout << "WebSocket connection closed" << std::endl;
};

// Add an event handler for the 'error' event
h.onError([](void *user) {
    std::cout << "WebSocket error" << std::endl;
});

// Run the event loop
h.run();
```

and I get "WebSocket error"